# Find appropriate initial value of an exponential trend model

Tags: linear-transformations, exponential-function

I was trying this exercise question but wasn't able to find a solution, so please help.

For the following trend model, $y={\mu}(x,{\beta})+{\epsilon = {\alpha-exp(-{\gamma}x)+{\epsilon}}}, {\alpha}>0, {\gamma}>0$,

where ${\beta}=({\alpha, {\gamma}})^T$. Then I was given a few given observations of x and y such as

(x1=1, y1=1.33;

x2=2, y2=1.55;

x3=4, y3=1.80;

x4=8, y4=1.96).

The question is to find appropriate initial values for $({\alpha0}, {\gamma}0)$.

I was trying to make a linear transformation for this model by using natural log but wasn't able to proceed as $log({\alpha}+exp(-{\gamma}x)+{\epsilon})$ does not give me too much insight...so please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall work with rational numbers to avoid losses of accuracy.

For the time being, just to simplify notations, replace $\gamma$ by $-\gamma$

Your equations are
$$\alpha -e^{-\gamma}=\frac {133}{100} \tag 1$$
$$\alpha -e^{-2\gamma}=\frac{31}{20} \tag 2$$
$$\alpha -e^{-4\gamma}=\frac{9}{5} \tag 3$$
$$\alpha -e^{-8\gamma}=\frac{49}{25} \tag 4$$

Now, subtracting
$$e^{-\gamma }-e^{-2 \gamma }=\frac{11}{50} \tag 5$$
$$e^{-2 \gamma }-e^{-4 \gamma }=\frac{1}{4} \tag 6$$
$$e^{-4 \gamma }-e^{-8 \gamma }=\frac{4}{25}\tag 7$$

Let $x=e^{-\gamma}$ and build the norm
$$\Phi=\left(x-x^2-\frac{11}{50}\right)^2+\left(x^2-x^4-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\left(x^4-x^8-\frac{4}{25}\right)^2$$ Expand
$$\Phi=x^{16}-2 x^{12}+\frac{58 x^8}{25}-2 x^6+\frac{109 x^4}{50}-2 x^3+\frac{47
   x^2}{50}-\frac{11 x}{25}+\frac{273}{2000}$$
$$\Phi'=16 x^{15}-24 x^{11}+\frac{464 x^7}{25}-12 x^5+\frac{218 x^3}{25}-6 x^2+\frac{47
   x}{25}-\frac{11}{25}$$ That is to say that we need to solution of
$$400 x^{15}-600 x^{11}+464 x^7-300 x^5+218 x^3-150 x^2+47 x-11=0$$ Plotting, we see that there is a single root close to $x=0.670$ that is to say $\gamma \sim-\log(0.670) \sim 0.400$.

Now, compute $(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)$ and solve for $\alpha$
$$\alpha=\frac{83}{50}+\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{-\gamma }+e^{-2\gamma }+e^{-4 \gamma }+e^{-8 \gamma }\right)$$ Replace $e^{-\gamma }$ by $0.670$ to get $\alpha\sim 2.00$.

Now, recompting the values, we find for the four rhs the values $$1.32968,1.55067,1.79810,1.95924$$

This almost looks like the solution.

**Edit**

If you want something much faster (probably in the mind of your teacher), you need $\alpha > 1.96$; so, say $\alpha_0=2$. Now, use $(5)$ which is a quadratic in $e^{-\gamma}$
$$x-x^2=\frac {11}{50} \implies x_\pm=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{3}}{10} $$
Now, look at $(6)$ for each of the values
$$x_+ \implies e^{-2 \gamma }-e^{-4 \gamma }=\frac{11 \left(39+10 \sqrt{3}\right)}{2500}\approx 0.24781$$ which is obviously fine.

So,
$$e^{-\gamma}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{3}}{10}\implies \gamma=-\log \left(\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{3}\right)\right)\sim 0.40$$